# Programar countdown en un board

Tags: c

Estoy intentando programar en lenguaje C un contador que comienza presionando el boton SW3 (switch 3) en mi placa electronica. Para ello he hecho un bucle while. Luego del while escribo los segmentos del contador que quiero que se muestren con setSSEG (Va del 20 al 0)

El problema viene cuando quiero presionar el boton SW4 (switch 4) para parar el contador y resetearlo.
Aunque escriba otro bucle while despues del primero para SW4:

```
while (!getSW3()) //Waits until SW3 gets pressed 
setSSEG1A;        //Set segments for numbers until 20...0
setSSEG2A;
...
while (!getSW4())  //Waits until SW4 gets pressed
clearSSEG1A;      //Clears all segments
clearSSEG2A;
...
```

, el primer bucle while para SW3 no se interrumpe y se compilan los 20 segundos hasta que termina en 0 e ignora el while con SW4.
Como podria interrumpir los segundos y resetearlo presionando el boton SW4?

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Todas esas instrucciones `setSSEG1A` se ejecutan de manera secuencial? De ser así es normal que nunca te actúe con el SW4 porque tienen que ejecutarse todas las instrucciones `set` que tienes antes de valorar tan siquiera el valor del SW4. Si estás programando con algún tipo de microcontrolador, te recomiendo emplear IRQ para controlar eventos externos y poder interrumpir el sistema cuando se detecten dichos eventos y valorar qué hacer en casa situación

Comment: ¿Otra opción más chapuza? Valorar constantemente entre funciones `set` el valor de SW4 y salir de un bucle que tengas valorando el evento de SW3